# javascript - Detect article tag content to assign article class automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm using blogger.com as my blogging platform right now. As we know, blogger is a very simple platform without any advanced programming language supported. It's only possible to do any trick with Javascript.

My post is about personal blog with some post format like Wordpress use, I have a standard post, audio post, and video post. I want to display post format icon based on my post format type, beside my post title. Video post will have video icon beside the title, audio post will have audio icon beside the title, etc...

This is my post markup:

```
<div class="post">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Post title</a>
    </h3>
    <!--content goes here-->
</div>
```

To make Javascript can identify my post format, I will add a tag inside my post like this: `<span data-format="audio-format"></span>` or `<span data-format="video-format"></span>`, etc...

```
<div class="post">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Post title</a>
    </h3>
    <span data-format="video-format"></span>
    <!--content goes here-->
</div>
```

Then javascript will add a class to my post markup, so I can set the icon based on CSS class trick. For example, if my post format is audio (`<span data-format="audio-format"></span>`), Javascript will add `audio-format` "CSS class" to my post markup.

```
<div class="post audio-format">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Post title</a>
    </h3>
    <span data-format="audio-format"></span>
    <!--content goes here-->
</div>
```

Unfortunately, my skill just HTML and CSS, I'm not fluent in Javascript or jQuery. Is it possible to do with Javascript trick?

PS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly:

```
$('div.post').has('span[data-format]').addClass(function() {
   var format = $('span[data-format]', this).data('format');
   return 'post-format-' + format.split('-')[0];
});
```

An alternative:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.post')).forEach(function(post) {
     var span = post.querySelector('span[data-format]');
     if (!span) return;
     var format = span.getAttribute('data-format').split('-')[0];
     post.classList.add('post-format-' + format);
});
```

**edit:** According to the changed markup you should just remove the split part.

```
$('div.post').addClass(function() {
   return $('span[data-format]', this).data('format');
});
```

Comment: It will actually result in _post-audio-post_ instead of _post-format-audio_. But my answer is a little longer, so I hope you will fix your one.

Comment: @Regent Yes, that's what happens when you don't test your code, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Without testing you were faster than I was with testing :) Now it's correct, +1.

Comment: Thank you @undefined. It's solve my problem. I want to +1 but my reputation still not enough :D